# SQL Server - ISNULL not working on Update Query

Tags: sql-server, isnull

Rather than have a NULL in a column, I want a 0 to be present.

Given the following two tables:

```
TABLE1
ClientID        OrderCount
1               NULL
2               NULL
3               NULL
4               NULL


Table2
ClientID        OrderCount
1               2
3               4
4               6
```

NOTE: The OrderCount column in both tables is `INT` datatype.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET OrderCount = ISNULL(TABLE2.OrderCount,0)
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.ClientID = TABLE1.CLIENTID
```

When I look at table1, I see this:

```
ClientID        OrderCount
1               2
2               NULL
3               4
4               6
```

So, I thought to myself - "Obviously, I should be using `NULLIF` and not `ISNULL`", so I reversed them.  Same result.

What am I doing wrong here?  How do I get a 0 rather than a `NULL` in the column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN`.  The records that don't have a matching `ClientID` are not even being touched by your query.

Answer (score 2):

you are using INNER JOIN but you don't have client ID 2 on table2 so your result set wont include a line with  2. Replace it with LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Your join is probably filtering out rows.